# Rails 5.1 - should I create a database index on primary_key and foreign_key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing, database-design, foreign-keys

Here is a migration to create a table:

```
class CreateTemplates < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :templates, id: :uuid do |t|
      t.references :account, type: :uuid, foreign_key: true
      t.string :name
      t.text :info
      t.string :title

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Since account_id is a foreign_key (and identifies the customer) it will appear in almost all (99%) of queries on this table - there is not much point in retrieving a template that belongs to another customer.

So should I drop the index the above migration created for the account_id foreign_key and create this one instead?

```
add_index :templates, [:id, :account_id], unique: false
```

Or should I keep the original and also add this?

**EDIT**

To clarify the 99% use case - I think I was mistaken there. When creating a template, the account_id is always inserted so that the index method of the tempaltes_controller will always return all templates using the account_id, so that a user only sees a list of templates belonging to their account. For edits, updates, deletes, those actions only need the template_id. So my 99% guess is wrong! Most queries won't actually need a composite key it seems to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If most of your queries are going to filter on a combination of **[:id, :account_id]**(which is unlikely) then creating a composite index will improve the performance of your queries.

However, it sounds like that most of your queries will only require **:account_id**, If that is the case then you do not need to add a composite index.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, you made me think a bit harder. I added an EDIT section to the question. I think most queries will just use the id field of the template table - only index action will need account_id (to only return templates for that account). So it seems most queries will require the template id on its own, rather than the account_id. So on that reasoning I think the composite key is not needed, right?

Comment: Yup, index on foreign_key should cover all the use cases you have listed. Id field is the primary key of templates, it already has an index on it.